# Chrome unload event when Browser is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, onunload

I am attempting to hookup the "unload" event to perform cleanup when the user navigates away from my page. In order to achieve this, synchronous requests are used - the following code is used:

```
        $(window).on('unload',function () { 
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('DELETE', '/myresource/lock', false);  // synchronous request
            request.send(null);
        });
```

This code works well on IE(!) and FF. 
In Chrome, it works on refresh or when closing a tab (even when only 1 tab is left). **However it fails when the window is closed using the "X" (top right).** 
I am aware of a plan to drop the support for synchronous request, however it seems odd that it works when the browser is closed one way, and not the other. 
Any insight or advice on how to work around this pb?